# ¿Por qué los arreglos de tamaño estático no pueden ser guardados en contenedores?

Tags: c++, contenedores

Tengo un alias a un arreglo de tamaño estático, es muy sencillo de usar:

```
using triplet_t = std::uint8_t[3];

//           vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- más fácil que std::uint8_t(&triplet)[3]
void f(const triplet_t &triplet) { /* whatever */ }

triplet_t t{}; // Tan bueno como std::uint8_t t[3]{};

t[0] = '0';
t[1] = '1';
t[2] = '2';
for (auto &v : t) std::cout << v << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';

// Todo correcto...
triplet_t t3[3]{};
for (auto &r : t3)
    for(auto &v : r)
        v = 42;
```

Incluso puedo usar el alias en contenedores:

```
std::vector<triplet_t> vt;
```

O eso pensaba, porque en el momento en que usas `vt` falla:

```
vt.push_back({});
```

> GCC 8.0.0 201711
>
> ```
> error: parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]
> { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
>   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> error: request for member '~unsigned char [3]' in '* __p', which is of non-class type 'unsigned char [3]'
> destroy(_Up* __p) { __p->~_Up(); }
>                     ~~~~~~^~~
> ```

El problema parece ser que después de desenrollar toda la brujería de las plantillas se llama a un placement-new al que se le pasan los parámetros entre paréntesis, y obviamente no es la manera de inicializar un arreglo de tamaño estático.

También, de alguna manera el contenedor cree que `triplet_t` es un objeto y por ello le pide un destructor, fallando de nuevo al compilar. El problema obviamente persiste sin el alias:

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t[3]> vt;
vt.push_back({});          // Mal!
vt.push_back({255, 0, 0}); // Error!
```

Pero no hay problema si se usa un objeto con la misma representación en memoria:

```
struct rgb { std::uint8_t r, g, b; };
std::vector<rgb> vt;
vt.push_back({});          // Bien!
vt.push_back({255, 0, 0}); // Genial!
```

Me pregunto por qué pasa esto. Hay alguna manera de guardar arreglos de tamaño estático en contenedores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el estándar C++: **26.2.1 General container requirements** se especifica que todos los contenedores de la biblioteca estándar requieren que los tipos de sus elementos sean ["Erasable"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Erasable), que no se cumple para un array.

Y con respecto a la segunda parte de la pregunta:

> Hay alguna manera de guardar arreglos de tamaño estático en
>   contenedores?

Podrías hacer:

```
using triplet_t = std::array<uint8_t, 3>;
```

Comment: Parece que los arreglos de tamaño estático incumplen varios requerimientos, no sólo el mencionado de "borrable".

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ¿A quién le parece? ¿Cuales?

Comment: Me refiero a que consultando el estándar, los tipos almacenados en `std::vector` deben ser `CopyInsertable` y/o `MoveInsertable` respecto a requerimiento `Erasable` ha ido cambiando de estándar a estándar ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster No, te equivocas; un array de estilo C cumple con `CopyInsertable` a la vez que con `MoveInsertable`.  (ver Estándar C++ 26.2.1 tabla 83 y **26.2.1.15.3**)

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y no cumple con `CopyInsertable` ya que [`allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v)` no es una expresión válida](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ANaavyd43PkG2m4G). Tampoco cumple ocn [`MoveInsertable` pues `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, rv)`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2VosD6ZS2fumjOjh) tampoco es una expresión válida.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Has equivocado los conceptos. Te sugiero poner una pregunta específica.

Comment: ¿Qué conceptos he equivocado? Según el párrafo del estándar que me has referido, para ser `CopyInsertable` la expresión `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v)` debe ser válida y para ser  `MoveInsertable` debe serlo la expresión `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, rv)`. Ninguna de las dos se cumple para un tipo `T[S]`, que es lo que estaba preguntando.

Answer (score 2):

Los arrays de tamaño fijo no pueden ser usados dentro de un contenedor porque el mismo impone varios requisitos sobre el tipo usado:

- Lo comentado por [@asdasdasd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/120166/463)
- El tipo debe admitir el constructor copia (o sintaxis move en su defecto) además del operador de asignación correspondiente.

  En el caso de los arrays de tamaño fijo esta característica no existe y se puede verificar con un ejemplo sencillo:

  ```
  int array1[10];
  int array2[10];
  array1 = array2; // error!!!
  ```

La mejor alternativa pasa, como ha propuesto  [@asdasdasd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/120166/463), por usar `std::array` ya que implementa las características de un array de tamaño fijo sin tener que sufrir las limitaciones del mismo.

Sin embargo, si alguien se empeña en usar un array de tamaño fijo, la solución pasa por usar un envoltorio que te permita evadir las restricciones:

```
template<class T>
class Wrapper;

template<class T, size_t SIZE>
class Wrapper<T[SIZE]>
{
  T data[SIZE];

  template<class TYPE>
  void InitFunc(size_t index, TYPE value)
  {
    data[index] = value;
  }

  template<class TYPE, class ...ARGS>
  void InitFunc(size_t index, TYPE value, ARGS... args)
  {
    data[index] = value;
    InitFunc(index+1,args...);
  }

public:

  using ArrayType = T[SIZE];

  Wrapper(T value)
  {
    for( size_t index=0; i<SIZE; i++ )
      data[index] = value;
  }

  template<class ...ARGS>
  Wrapper(ARGS... args)
  {
    InitFunc(0,args...);
  }

  T& operator[](size_t index)
  { return data[index]; }

  T operator[](size_t index) const
  { return data[index]; }

  operator ArrayType&()
  { return data; }
};
```

Su mecánica es muy sencilla:

La definición básica del envoltorio está incompleta, luego no va a compilar. La única especialización que vale, por el momento, es la que gestiona un array de tamaño `SIZE`. Este envoltorio viene preparado para ofrecer la funcionalidad básica:

- operador de indización `[]`.
- conversión implícita al tipo contenido (para extraer el array almacenado).
- Permite inicializar los elementos directamente desde el constructor.

Su uso es bastante simple:

```
std::vector<Wrapper<triplet_t>> vt;
```

E incluso admite inicializaciones por lista de inicialización:

```
std::vector<Wrapper<triplet_t>> vt { {'0','1','2'}, {'3','4','5'}, {'6','7','8'}};
```

Y esto se puede probar con un código sencillo:

```
void f(const triplet_t & /*triplet */) { /* whatever */ }

int main()
{
  std::vector<Wrapper<triplet_t>> vt { {'0','1','2'}, {'3','4','5'}, {'6','7','8'}};

  for( auto triplet : vt )
  {
    std::cout << triplet[0] << ' ' << triplet[1] << ' ' << triplet[2] << '\n';
    f(triplet);
  }
}
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando <kbd>[aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5oE1LJ4FWGnaPoAa)</kbd>

Como ya he indicado en otras ocasiones, este tipo de envoltorios tienen la ventaja de que el compilador es capaz de eliminarlos al generar el código final, luego su impacto en términos de rendimiento es 0.